# What cipher suites does an Amazon Classic ELB support for health checking?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I can't find this in the documentation anywhere, but I am having the same problem as https://vcsjones.com/2015/07/23/aws-elastic-load-balancers-and-https-healthchecks/ - my health checks are failing and my logs say that the cipher suite can't be negotiated.  Currently supporting:

`tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,`

Comment: If users with modern browsers can get to it, ELB should be able to. Have you tried expanding your cypher suite temporarily to see if it's the problem?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes: adding TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 resolved the problem.  Seems like the ECDHE ciphers are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the ECDHE ciphers are not supported.  Adding TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 to our api suite resolved the issue.

Comment: ...but be aware that perfect forward secrecy won't be provided with following cipher suite since it uses RSA for the key exchange.